# principle of persistent inequality Real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Not sure where to go with this proof.

> Prove if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ and continuous on $[-1,1]$ and $f(0)>g(0)$, then there is a sub-interval $I$ contained on in $[-1,1]$ such that $f(x)>g(x)\, ∀x I ⊆ [-1,1]$.

**Proof**

Using principle of persistent inequality, Since $f(x)$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$ and $f(x)>g(x) ∀x I ⊆ [-1,1]$.  Let $H(x)= f(x)-g(x)$.

Note:
$H(x)>0 $
....

Answer (score 1):

Define $h(x) = f(x)-g(x)$. Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous we know that $h$ is. We also note that $h(0)>0$. Now take $\epsilon = h(0)/2$. Now there exist a $\delta >0$ such that $|h(x)-h(0)|< \epsilon$ whenever $|x|< \delta$. But if $|h(x)-h(0)| < h(0)/2$ then $h(x)>0$ for $|x|<\delta$. Hence $f(x)>g(x)$ when $|x|< \delta$.

**Detail:**
$|h(x)-h(0)|< \epsilon $ is equivalent to $h(0)-\epsilon < h(x) < h(0)+\epsilon$. So especially in our case $h(x) > h(0)-\epsilon = h(0)-h(0)/2 =h(0)/2 >0.$

Comment: Thank you, sir.  You have been a great help.

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer is satisfactory then please accept it by clicking the "check mark" to the left of my post.